# Access, Compilation errors and runtime

Tags: database, ms-access, runtime

I have a Database that I need to use, but it has some errors which I have to fix.
Since I am not an expert in MS-Access, I can not figure out where the mistakes are.

The first error

```
Run-time. Could not find field '| 1' to which reference is made in the expression.
```

is thrown when pressing the print button.

[image]

Opening the debug, I found this piece of code:

```
Private Sub Pulsante40_Click()

    If Me!Campo51 = False Then
        Select Case [schede]![S_Stampa_Ordini].[ordinamento]
            Case 1
                DoCmd.OpenReport "Stampa Ordini BY DATA", , , " (DATA_AGG Between #" & Format$(Me.[Dal], "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# And #" & Format$(Me.[Al], "mm/dd/yyyy") & " 23:59#) AND Tipo = """ & Me.TipoL & """"
            Case 2
                DoCmd.OpenReport "Stampa Ordini BY CLIENTE", , , " (DATA_AGG Between #" & Format$(Me.[Dal], "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# And #" & Format$(Me.[Al], "mm/dd/yyyy") & " 23:59#) AND Tipo = """ & Me.TipoL & """"
            Case 3
                DoCmd.OpenReport "Stampa Ordini BY LAVORAZION", , , " (DATA_AGG Between #" & Format$(Me.[Dal], "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# And #" & Format$(Me.[Al], "mm/dd/yyyy") & " 23:59#) AND Tipo = """ & Me.TipoL & """"
            Case 4
                DoCmd.OpenReport "Stampa Ordini BY DATA_CONS", , , " (DATA_AGG Between #" & Format$(Me.[Dal], "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# And #" & Format$(Me.[Al], "mm/dd/yyyy") & " 23:59#) AND Tipo = """ & Me.TipoL & """"
        End Select
        FDipendente = 0
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenForm "FiltroStampa", , , , , A_DIALOG
    End If

End Sub
```

It gives me error on line:

```
Select Case [schede]![S_Stampa_Ordini].[ordinamento]
```

The second error

```
Compile Error, could not find the method or data member
```

is thrown when I open the mask minutes and select

```
 Legno, or Lavorazione Ext
```

[image]

code:

```
Private Sub Tipo_AfterUpdate()
    Select Case Me.Tipo
        Case "C"
            Me.[SSMin-In].scheda.testo0.Caption = "Lavorazione:"
        Case "L"
            Me.[SSMin-In].scheda.testo0.Caption = "Cod.Prev.:"
        Case "E"
            Me.[SSMin-In].scheda.testo0.Caption = "Cod.Prev.:"
    End Select
End Sub
```

It gives me the error on line:

> Private Sub Tipo_AfterUpdate()

It has been days that I'm trying to solve the Database, or at least to start studying the visual basic to understand something. Unfortunately I only know java and my colleagues can not help me. Thank you in advance for an answer and I apologize if I was unclear or did not provide enough information.

Comment: While in the code window, have you tried from the menu bar debug->compile. (you as a general rule need to compile your code before you test/try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your code is trying to refer to controls on your form, but in an invalid way (I can't quite understand what the code is trying to do because I don't read the language, and I don't know what controls you have on the form).

For example, to get the value of a combo box on a form, you would normally type something like `Me.cboMyCombo.Value`. To get the value of a field bound to this form, you would type something like `Me!MyField` or `Me![My Field].Value`.

Your calls to `[schede]![S_Stampa_Ordini].[ordinamento]` and `Me.[SSMin-In].scheda.testo0.Caption` look like they have a few too many methods on the end.

One way to find out what methods are acceptable is to start typing and let the pop-up menus guide you. For example, type `Me.` and see what pops up. In my example, `cboMyCombo` would be one of the items in the menu. Choose it, and you will see a new menu with `Value` as a choice.

You can also use the ['Expression Builder'](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/using-the-expression-builder-HP005186638.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to copy your SQL into a query (or two). Make sure they actually produce the results you want. Then, you can call `DoCmd.OpenQuery "qappYourNewQueryName"`. It is easier to read.

```
INSERT INTO [MIN-OUT] 
    ( LAVORAZION, TIPO, MINUTI ) 
SELECT DISTINCTROW 
    [MIN-IN].LAVORAZION, 
    [MIN-IN].TIPO, 
    0 FROM [MIN-IN] 
GROUP BY 
    [MIN-IN].LAVORAZION, 
    [MIN-IN].TIPO;

' What is this?
, ID_Dipendente ) 

SELECT DISTINCTROW 
    [MIN-IN].LAVORAZION, 
    [MIN-IN].TIPO, 
    [Forms]![Minuti].[dipendente] AS Espr1 
FROM [MIN-IN] 
GROUP BY 
    [MIN-IN].LAVORAZION, 
    [MIN-IN].TIPO, 
    [Forms]![Minuti].[dipendente];")
```